# automount usb drive when connected to /mnt/ssd/ instead of /media/user/uuid

Tags: usb, mount, ssd, automount, drive

Trying to make a usb ssd automount itself to /mnt/ssd when it's connected to laptop.

Instead of /media/user/UUID-******-*******.
The ssd will be connected after the system boots. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Output:

```
user@laptop:~$ lsusb | grep Samsung
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 04e8:61f5 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 

user@laptop:~$ lsblk | grep sde
sde      8:64   0 465.8G  0 disk /mnt/ssd

user@laptop:~$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sde: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

1) Open the **disks** tool

2) Then click on the disk you want to change the mount options

3) Then click on the little **settings icon**

4) Then click on **edit mount option**

5) Disable **User Session Defaults**

6) Then tick on **Mount at system startup**

7) Then choose the location where you want to mount your SSD

8) To show your SSD with the name rather than UUID select **LABEL=XXXXX** (Click on the drop-down list of ** Identify As** option)this will display your SSD with name